# formatting the x-axis exponential plot in R as a^x?

Tags: r, formatting, axis, exponent

I have generated this plot in R with some strange numbers format in the x-axis:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmy89.png)
 I want to have in the x-axis the numbers in the format (ax) as   2^6, 6^6, 10^6.  this would simplify the x-axis to get data in all points. Please do you have any suggestions?

Here my code :

```
data=read.csv("my_file.csv",row.names = 1)
plot(genes~Prot,cex=1.5,data, function(x) 10^x, xlab="Proteome 
size(codons)",ylim=c(0,30), ylab="Genes in pathway")
abline(lm(prot~genes,data),lty=2, lwd=3,col="black")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xaxt` = 'n' as an argument to `plot` to turn off the x-axis labelling.  Then use the `Axis` function to set tick marks and label as required.

```
# Generating some data
power <- seq(1, 6, length.out = 20) 
Prot = 10^power
genes <- runif(20, min = 5, max = 30)

# plotting
plot(x= Prot, y= genes, cex=1.5, xlab="Proteome size(codons)", ylab="Genes in pathway", xaxt = 'n', log = 'xy')
Axis(at = c(2^6, 6^6, 10^6), side = 1, labels = c('2^6', '6^6', '10^6'), las = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , this  is very helpful !